# File not found error while using pandas in django

Tags: python, django, pandas

I have written a naive bayes classifier for text messages and it's script is as follows:

**tester.py**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

df = pd.read_table('a.txt', sep='\t', header=None, names=['label', 'text'])
...
```

On testing, it worked correctly. Now I have created a django project where this script and the a.txt file are placed alongside views.py and urls.py. When user enters a comment, it is processed in views file as:

**views.py**

```
from .tester import predictor    
def result(request):
        content = request.POST['content']
        res = predictor(content)
        status = ''
        if res == 0:
            status = 'not spam'    
        else:
            status = 'spam'    
        return render(request, 'spammer/result.html', {'status':status,})
```

Where predictor is a function I have added to tester.py:

```
def predictor(comment):
    tester = [comment]
    contest = count_vector.transform(tester) #count_vector=CountVectorizer()
    a = naive_bayes.predict(contest)  #naive_bayes=MultinomialNB()
    return a[0]
```

However on running the server, there is an error:

```
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: File b'a.txt' does not exist
```

which is not the case. Where am I going wrong? I have installed pandas,scipy,sklearn in virtual environment using pip and tester.py as well as a.txt are in the same directory as views.py,urls.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your filesystem looks like:

```
yourproject
├── yourapp
│        ├── __init__.py
│        ├── settings.py
│        ├── urls.py
│        ├── views.py
│        └── a.txt
└── manage.py
```

And you run it like

```
python manage.py runserver
```

So your working directory is `yourproject/`, while your file is relatively located at `yourapp/a.txt`.

What counts it's your working directory, aka the directory from where you run the python command. Not the current Python file location.

Comment: I'm not Django expert, it may exists a dedicated place / best practice for that, but I would create a `yourproject/data/` folder to store my raw files. so you access it with path `data/a.txt`